# Easiest Path or Toolkit toward Ubiquitous Site Login Capability?

Tags: jquery, authentication, openid, windows-live-id

I've already plugged in Facebook integration with a "Log In with Facebook" button.  It works fine, but I'm wondering if there's a toolkit or a known path of least resistance to moving toward "log in with ..." (Google, LiveId, Twitter, or whatever).  I am using ASP.NET MVC (C#) on the back end and jQuery on the front end.

I'd love it if there were one toolkit that plugged in all this functionality without reinventing it one at a time.

Thanks!